# Why is my Bootstrap checkbox always checked?

Tags: django

I'm using django-bootstrap for my Django project. A user of the website can create/update his posts, where one of the fields is Boolean field(`is_public`).

The problem is, even when the user saved Boolean field as False, when he enters the update page the checkbox is checked.

I first thought the data is not properly saved or passed to template, but it turns out it's not the case. Nothing is wrong with the backend logic. I checked this in my template.

```
{{form.is_public}} Can be public. 
{{form.is_public.value}} <!-- Gives "False" which is correct -->
```

So to wrap up, the value is passed correctly, but the checkbox is always checked by default. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Please share the code for the form. Maybe one also needs to see the code of the view. I suppose you set some defaults, or initial values at either form or view level. That would overwrite the data coming from the database. But without the code... no one can tell.